# Kotlin Firebase Deserialization

Tags: java, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to deserialize data from Firebase to POJO with Kotlin, this is my POJO class:

```
class Message {
var number: String ?= null
var message: String? = null
var timestamp: Long = 0L
var isHandled: Boolean ?= false
var type:String ?=null
}
```

and this is my code to retrieve data from Firebase

```
val query = Fire.REF.child("sms").orderByChild("type").equalTo("outbox-unsent")
    query.addChildEventListener(object : ChildEventListener {
        override fun onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, key: String) {
            val outbox = dataSnapshot.getValue(Message::class.java)
            Log.d("BS", "Background Service $outbox")
           }
//......
});
```

this is my data structure on Firebase look like

```
"sms":{
"-KI3ar91oBXGNpXXrOCS" : {
"handled" : false,
"message" : "Pak kenapa koneksi...",
"number" : "+6285830166314",
"timestamp" : 1463587399000,
"type" : "inbox"
},
//.......//
}
```

When I execute the code it raises an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter specified as non-null is null: method kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull, parameter key
```

Where is my mistake on above code?

Comment: I don't have any experience with firebase, but it looks like the parameter `key` in the eventlistener is null. Can you change the parameter of onChildAdded to be `String?` and try again?

Comment: My bad, yes I traced the second parameter which is possibly null.
Thanks

Comment: Is this resolved? Can someone post a working solution to close the question?

Comment: As Augusto said above, Kotlin is null-safe, but on above function, the key parameter may null.
So the code should like this `onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, key: String?)` add question mark after key parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Augusto said above, Kotlin is null-safe, but on above function, the *key* parameter may null.
So the code should like this

```
onChildAdded(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot, key: String?)
```

**Add question mark** after key parameter